# How can I redirect all http request from http://localhost/site/* to http://localhost/site/admin

Tags: .htaccess

```
http://localhost/site/contactus.php
http://localhost/site/aboutus.php
http://localhost/site/home.php
```

how can I route all of these request to

```
http://localhost/site/admin/index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `/site/.htaccess` you can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/

RewriteRule ^[^/]+?\.php$ admin/index.php [L,NC]
```